# Browser Compatibility of innerHTML

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I have a simple function to refresh a table. It simply creates a table in a div. It works fine in safari and chrome. But for some reason it is not working in firefox. Can anyone suggest me some alternative of this so that it works in firefox as well?

Here's my code -

```
function tableRefresh(){
     POIdiv.innerHTML=" <table id='POITable' border='1' > <tr><td>POI</td><td>Latitude</td><td>Longitude</td><td>Delete?</td></tr><tr  id='tr1'><td id='poinum'>1</td><td><input size=25 type='text' id='latbox' readonly=true/></td><td><input size=25 type='text' id='lngbox' readonly=true/></td><td><input type='button' id=1 value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow_addPOI(this.id)'/></td></tr></table>";
     }
```

This function is called under a button's onclick event.

::::::::::EDIT:::::::::::::

Please try the following link -

http://128.233.104.33/passgui/editLeveledit.php?dbname=reganTest3

Now do these -

1. click on map to add some points
2. click on "Add the new POIs"

It should upgrade both the tables. Please try it in Google Chore/ Safari first then try it in Firefox. You can find the difference.

Thanks

Comment: You must add more code in your question. Your question sounds as _"Browser Compatibility of **AJAX**"_. But no AJAX related code is found. If `POIdiv` is defined in all browsers and points to `DIV` this code must works in all browsers, including FF.

Comment: `<input type='button' id=1 value='Delete'`. `id` attribute value must be started with letter: `id='a1'`.

Answer (score 1):

Define "not work"; it works fine for me on my [jsfiddle test](http://jsfiddle.net/davelnewton/vD9Ah/) in Firefox, with a slight modification since we don't know how you're setting/getting the POIdiv variable.

Comment: Well ... Not work means ... it does not update the div .. it shows me the same div even if I call that event. I'm adding some more details in my question.

Comment: Which div? The top table adds a row when I click the map no matter what browser I'm in. The bottom table updates when I click "Add the new POIs" no matter what browser I try. (With the caveat that I'm not trying IE.)

Comment: Yes ... but when you delete from the bottom table, it does not delete the row from firefox..

Comment: I did it earlier cause it was not even working .. I tried Joe's suggestion and it worked but the delete part was not working as well. I apologize for not mentioning that.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
POIdiv.innerHTML=...
```

to

```
document.getElementById('POIdiv').innerHTML=...
```

Comment: Thanks ... that works for the 'POITable' .... but it does not work for the bigger 'dataTable' when a value is deleted. If you can see my source code, it's in line 396.